# App crash on creating ViewModel only when minifyEnabled and with LifeCycle v 2.1.0

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-lifecycle

My app is crashing on launch with a `LinkageError` when creating a view model using `lazy{}`. The crash only happens when:

1. `minifyEnabled` is set to `true` in build.gradle, AND
2. I use *ver. 2.1.0* of lifecycle components. It works fine with `lifecycle-2.0.0` with `minifyEnabled`

```
    def lifecycle_version = '2.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Also, the crash is only happening for one of the view models. Other view models in the same activity that are touched before this one, aren't crashing the app.

---

The crash happens on the second line here:

```
    private val searchStackViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SearchStateViewModel::class.java]
    }
```

The `SearchStateViewModel` is:

```
class SearchStateViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // Live data that initialises to empty stack with SearchStack.init
    private val privateStack = MutableLiveData<SearchStack>().apply {
        value = SearchStack()
    }

    // Observable view of search stack so it can't be directly modified
    internal val stateStack : LiveData<SearchStack> = privateStack

    /**
     * Add state to stack
     */
    fun add(searchState: SearchState) {
        val current = privateStack.value ?: SearchStack()
        current.add(searchState)
        privateStack.value = current
    }

    /**
     * Clear stack
     */
    fun clear() {
        val current = privateStack.value ?: SearchStack()
        current.clear()
        privateStack.value = current
    }

    /**
     * Clear stack, then add current state as the only state
     */
    fun clearThenAdd(searchState: SearchState) {
        val current = privateStack.value ?: SearchStack()
        current.clear()
        current.add(searchState)
        privateStack.value = current
    }

    /**
     * Get currentState search state, without changing the stack
     */
    fun currentState(): SearchState {
        return privateStack.value?.last() ?: SearchState()
    }

    /**
     * Return currentState search state, and remove it from the stack
     */
    fun pop(): SearchState {
        val current = privateStack.value ?: SearchStack()
        val poppedState = current.pop()
        privateStack.value = current
        return poppedState
    }
}
```

`SearchStack` is just an ArrayList:

```
class SearchStack : ArrayList<SearchState>() {

    init {
        add(SearchState())
    }


    fun pop(): SearchState = if (lastIndex > 0) removeAt(lastIndex) else last()


    override fun clear() {
        super.clear()
        add(SearchState())
    }


    override fun add(element: SearchState): Boolean {
        if (element == lastOrNull())
            return false
        return super.add(element)
    }
}
```

And `SearchState` is a data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class SearchState(
        val searchTerm: String = "",
        val isComplete: Boolean? = null,
        val dueOnly: Boolean = false,
        val aliveOnly: Boolean = true,
        val priority: Char? = null,
        val project: String? = null,
        val priorityMatchType: PriorityMatchType? = null,
        val name: String = "",
        val hideThresholdTasks: Boolean = true,
        val sortOrder: Int = -1,
        val sortOrderString: String? = null
                      ) : Parcelable {

    enum class PriorityMatchType {
        GREATOR,
        LESSOR,
        EXACT
    }

    enum class TaskState {
        DUE,
        PENDING,
        COMPLETED,
        ALL
    }
```

---

Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.c306.ttsuper, PID: 7380
    java.lang.LinkageError: i.a.a.o.b
1 >>    at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity$v.b(SourceFile:182)
        at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity$v.b(SourceFile:159)
        at g.j.a(SourceFile:74)
        at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity.F(SourceFile)
2 >>    at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity.c(SourceFile:1839)
        at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity.a(SourceFile:1993)
        at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity.a(SourceFile:1967)
        at net.c306.ttsuper.view.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:386)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Line labeled (1) is the lazy create of ViewModel where the crash happens.
Line labeled (2) is the first access of ViewModel that initiates the lazy creation:

```
val lastState = searchStackViewModel.currentState()
```

Comment: post the crash stacktrace

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Added the stack trace.

Comment: Can anyone explain, why is it happening? Because we are not using overriding keyword here? Moreover for me it's happening only in release version where proguard is enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have probably resolved this. Turns out that in `lifecycle-2.0.0`, the ViewModel class has a public method `clear()`:

```
    @MainThread
    final void clear() {
        mCleared = true;
        // Since clear() is final, this method is still called on mock objects
        // and in those cases, mBagOfTags is null. It'll always be empty though
        // because setTagIfAbsent and getTag are not final so we can skip
        // clearing it
        if (mBagOfTags != null) {
            synchronized (mBagOfTags) {
                for (Object value : mBagOfTags.values()) {
                    // see comment for the similar call in setTagIfAbsent
                    closeWithRuntimeException(value);
                }
            }
        }
        onCleared();
    }
```

My `SearchStackViewModel` also has a completely unrelated `clear()` method.

```
    /**
     * Clear stack
     */
    fun clear() {
        val current = privateStack.value ?: SearchStack()
        current.clear()
        privateStack.value = current
    }
```

When `minifyEnabled` is on, there appears to be a conflict between the two, hence the Linkage error. I renamed my method and the crashes stopped.