# java.lang.LinkageError: Method void GameHistoryViewModel.a() overrides final method in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel; appears in base.apk)

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, androidx, dagger

When i migrate to Androidx encountered this error only release build.I tried to update depenencies but doesnt work.Its working perfectly before androidx.I didnt understand.Thanks for help.
When i migrate to Androidx encountered this error only release build.I tried to update depenencies but doesnt work.Its working perfectly before androidx.I didnt understand.Thanks for help.

Complete Error

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Method void com.kaznmx.app.kelime.features.gamehistory.GameHistoryViewModel.a() overrides final method in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel; (declaration of 'com.kaznmx.app.kelime.features.gamehistory.GameHistoryViewModel' appears in base.apk)
        at com.kaznmx.app.kelime.WordSearchApp.onCreate(:2)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5940)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

WordSearchApp Class

```
package com.kaznmx.app.kelime;

import android.app.Application;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
import com.kaznmx.app.kelime.di.component.*;

import com.kaznmx.app.kelime.di.modules.AppModule;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

/**
 * Created by abdularis on 18/07/17.
 */

public class WordSearchApp extends Application {

    AppComponent mAppComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                .withLogEnabled(true)
                .build(this, "WJ634G9DD5HTFTHFKVFDZ");
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return mAppComponent;
    }

}
```

BuildGradle(App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

android {



    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: '09f73c28-30df-4539-8e50-3da31c027731',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: '712447187723'
        ]
    }

    signingConfigs {

        test {
            storePassword 'test1234'
            keyAlias = 'key0'
            keyPassword 'test1234'
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\Onur\\test1234.jks')
        }
    }
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parakazanin.cevirkazangorevyap"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.test
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2, 3.99.99]'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.abdularis:CircularImageView:v1.2'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"

}
```

Mapping.txt

```
com.kaznmx.app.kelime.features.gamehistory.GameHistoryViewModel -> com.kaznmx.app.kelime.features.gamehistory.GameHistoryViewModel:
    com.kaznmx.app.kelime.data.GameDataSource mGameDataSource -> a
```

Comment: Also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995480/app-crash-on-creating-viewmodel-only-when-minifyenabled-and-with-lifecycle-v-2-1

Comment: accidentally I have take boolean variable name as 'isResumed' and because of that I am facing this issue, after rename its work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem recently 。 you can check the implementation about androidx.appcompat.xxxxx`。 I fixup by replace`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`to`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 23):

I think it's because you have a method named `clear()`, which is a final method of higher version of ViewModel class. If that's the case, you can resolve this issue by changing your method's name.